# How to test my script in a github repo which is dependent upon other files in the repo

Tags: python, git, file, testing, github

In my github repository, I have a python script say `script.py`.
I want to check if this produces the desired output or not? 
I can copy the code of this file ad run it on my local machine but this `script.py` is using functions and modules from other files in the repository as well. So I cannot simply copy `script.py` and run it to test it.

So what should I do? How do I make sure that this produces the right output?

I am very new to git and VC so please answer elaborately.

Comment: Is there something wrong with cloning the entire repo to your computer?

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Not if it depends on other files in the repo, I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

why you don't clone your repository and run your script?

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do.

First, try to think GitHub as a place only to put your code, without any other functionalities (which actually is not the case). So if you want to run a script `script.py` and it depends on other files in the same repo, then you have to download at least itself and the files it depends on, more easily just download the entire repo. This is also the easiest way since if there are updates in the remote repo, you can `pull` the change to your local repo. It guarantees you have the same content between remote and local.

And yes, there are other ways. Like @yflelion said, you can try travis CI (or any CI). Think of CI being some program runners, and once you have some code changes it will run though some pre-defined code and make sure all of them are correct. This approach leads you into the concept of software testing and DevOps. It requires a lot more work than just simply clone the repo and run, but it is automated and can assure the code quality through an intensive and long developing process of a product.

BTW just out of curiosity, why are you trying *not* to clone the repository? Is there any non-trivial reason?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know if github has some functionality related to my question. I thought all the big projects which contain a lot of files and directories might be using something about which I don't know.

Comment: afaik I don't think it is possible to run _a script_ in a repo in any version control system / service. Say, if a script depends on other 2 files which depends on another 3 packages, how can GitHub determine that, is it going to compile the whole repo for you and run a single script? Even more, the compile commands are different for different languages, some might require external runtime platform.  It is just out of scope for a VCS.